# Android DroidGap disabling back button

Tags: android, cordova, back-button

Please, anyone suggest, how can I disable back button press event while working with `PhoneGap`?

I need to do something in my `Activity`, (`DroidGap` code) for controlling the back button event.

Even, the following code works well in my `Activity`, but not working when being used with `DroidGap`.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
         //preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
         return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `setOnKeyListener` on `appView` helped me out.

I just had to make a minor change in my above code snippet, which is as follows:

```
appView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() { 
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            return true;
        }
        return onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    } 
});
```

**EDITED**

There actually occurs two actions while key-pressing event - `Action Up` & `Action Down`

So, the following should be used in order to get the key event.

```
appView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() { 
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // Do Here whatever you want 
            return true;
        }
        return onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: @PnestecDev: Are you trying to do something on your back button click?

Comment: Yes i am trying to navigate the pages on back click.

Comment: @NarendraDroidWorm I implemented as per your answer... and the event is fired on click of device back button... when i click a device back button nothing should be happened.... Can u please help me how to acheive that?

Comment: just comment / remove the event you performed on back button click.

Comment: Also please remove -- event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP from the condition.

Answer (score 5):

Slightly better than Narendra's version. It can handle key up calls for key presses other than back button properly. Put the code below inside onCreate override for example.

```
appView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() { 

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    // Do Stuff Here
                    return true;
                }
                return onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
            }
            return onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
        } 
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I use Javascript + jquery like so:

```
$(document).on('backbutton',
     function(e){

         e.preventDefault();

         // do whatever you like here.

});
```

Comment: does not work for me. jQ 1.8.3 + jQM 1.3.2 on Android (Motorola Razor)

Answer (score 0):

```
// ************ stop the back button  *****************

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

    return true;
}
```