# Android - Disable Device Back button

Tags: android, cordova, back-button

I am working on android application using PhoneGap. I need to handle Device back button functionality by using the below code:

```
 import com.phonegap.DroidGap;
 public Class MyClass extends DroidGap {
 appView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() { 
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                finish();
                return true;
            }
            return onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
        } 
    });
  }
```

By using the above code, Application getting exited because i have used `finish();` But i want nothing should be happened on click of Device back button. How can i acheive that? Please help me.

Comment: Remove the finish call, or I don't understand your question...

Comment: The Back button can not be disabled on unrooted devices, security issues ..

Comment: Check this post out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834629/android-droidgap-disabling-back-button?rq=1

Comment: @Tinus81 yes, i followed that link and implemented as `appView`.. Can u please check the code i have placed??

Comment: did u tried removing finish() and return false?

Comment: @g00dy i am using the device which is unrooted... still it is not working...

Comment: @R9j still i am able to navigate to the previous pages....not helpful...

Comment: @AvadhaniY - You want the Back button to be "non-functionning" - right? That's not possible by default. What you can do is to control the behaviour - if the back is pressed, the same aActivity gets loaded again, with the same views etc. You can not disable this button! However, the keypresses are controlled (called) only from an Activity, so you can start from there.

Comment: @g00dy FYI, i am using `Phonegap`.... as `super.loadUrl("MY URL");`... The Device back button can be disabled in native code as `@Override
 public void onBackPressed(){
            finish();
         }`... In the same way how can i disable for a PhoneGap application... Can u please help in that way....

Comment: @AvadhaniY The code you pasted exits the application - right? because it looks like the case to me ?

Comment: Yes, The application exists with the above code i have placed.... but i want "do nothing" on click of Device back button... How can i acheive that

Comment: in the if condition again keep if(appView.canGoBack()){appView.goBack(); return whaturequired;} it and try...

Comment: @Harish i dont need to goBack... What i want is if Back is clicked nothing should happen....

Comment: then why you are writtem finish() in onbackbuttonpress?

Comment: @Harish I just written for verifying that method is called or not onclick of Device back button... I am asking help to replace that line with the code that do nothing on click of device back button... can u help me in that way...???

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why do you need to do this at the Java level? You can achieve this with Javascript using Phonegap's [Event API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton)

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Yeah i know how to do using `Phonegap`... but the problem is there are 100s of HTML pages in the server and i dont have a chance to handle/modify HTML content.. so, i am trying to get it done in Java level.. Cant i get through Java anyway...?

Comment: e.preventDefault(); is not working. I'm trying to remove the default event from android device back button and I tried the above code but no luck the application is still returning from previous page

Comment: This code must be inside of "deviceready" event listener. If you are writing this directly into HTML, check also if you have 'unsafe-inline' in default-src to allow javascript inlining.

Comment: Instead of ```e.preventDefault```, you should use ```return false```. In my experience, calling ```e.preventDefault``` will cause ALL further events in Angular to be prevented. It's weird, but ```return false``` has the expected result.