# Disable button back on android devices, in IONIC

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework

I'm new to this theme ionic. 
I read in several places I researched it does not work for me.

I would like to know how to do that when a person  Press the button "back" of the cell not redirected to a previous state or to another view. I want that when the button is pressed "back" button of the Cell nothing happens.

I tried with this code, but it is the same thing happening, the button "back" my android device redirects me to another view of my application

```
$ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function() {
 event.preventDefault();
 event.stopPropagation();
 alert('nothing');
});
```

I'm putting my code, in this part, I'm not sure if it's the right place:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {

 $ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function() {
 event.preventDefault();
 event.stopPropagation();
 alert('nothing');
});

$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {  
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with Javascript using Phonegap's [Event API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton)

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

[Ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875299/android-disable-device-back-button)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it

```
ion-view title=""  hide-nav-bar="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you will have to completely overide the back button functionality.
To do this replace your current code with this one:

```
 $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e){
    //do your stuff
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  },101);
```

Answer is mentioned in [Ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-backbutton-event-best-pratice/3577/9)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
 .run(['$rootScope', '$ionicPlatform','$state',
        function($rootScope, $ionicPlatform,$state){    
        $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      },101);

    }])
```